# How to display Total Time Duration and Current Time of video

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I want to display time duration of a video in silverlight 3.0 application. The format should be like 00:20 / 05:00 . ( Current Video time / Total Video Time). How to get it??.

Answer (score 1):

```
    TimeSpan _duration = mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
    var totalTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (_duration.Hours * 60) + _duration.Minutes, _duration.Seconds);

    TimeSpan remaining = _duration.Subtract(mediaElement.Position);
    var currentTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (remaining.Hours * 60) + remaining.Minutes, remaining.Seconds);

     string result = string.formar("{0}/{1}",totalTime,currentTime);
```

Try this, Hope this can help.

Regards.